# weird problem - change event fires only under debug in IE

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have form autocomplete code that executes when value changes in one textbox. It looks like this:

```
$('#myTextBoxId)').change(function () {
    var caller = $(this);
    var ajaxurl = '@Url.Action("Autocomplete", "Ajax")';
    var postData = { myvalue: $(caller).val() }
        executeAfterCurrentAjax(function () {
            //alert("executing after ajax");
            if ($(caller).valid()) {
                //alert("field is valid");
                $.ajax({ type: 'POST',
                    url: ajaxurl,
                    data: postData,
                    success: function (data) {
                        //some code that handles ajax call result to update form
                        }
                    });
                }
            });
        });
```

As this form field (myTextBoxId) has remote validator, I have made this function:

```
function executeAfterCurrentAjax(callback) {
    if (ajaxCounter > 0) {
        setTimeout(function () { executeAfterCurrentAjax(callback); }, 100);
    }
    else {
        callback();
    }
}
```

This function enables me to execute this autocomplete call after remote validation has ended, resulting in autocomplete only when textbox has valid value. `ajaxCounter` variable is global, and its value is set in global ajax events:

```
$(document).ajaxStart(function () {
        ajaxCounter++;
    });
$(document).ajaxComplete(function () {
        ajaxCounter--;
        if (ajaxCounter <= 0) {
            ajaxCounter = 0;
        }
    });
```

My problem is in IE (9), and it occurs only when I normally use my form. Problem is that function body inside executeAfterCurrentAjax(function () {...}); sometimes does not execute for some reason. If I uncomment any of two alerts, everything works every time, but if not, ajax call is most of the time not made (I checked this by debugging on server). If I open developer tools and try to capture network or debug javascript everything works as it should.

Comment: Just a thought, but IE's JavaScript engine is fairly picky about what it considers valid code. This line, `var postData = { myvalue: $(caller).val() }` needs a semi-colon at the end to complete the object definition. Shouldn't make a difference, but you never know...

Comment: +1 Tieson's comment - same goes for trailing commas in lists - most other browsers are OK with that, but IE is not. Otherwise this sounds like a textbook Heisenbug ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that problem occurs when field loses focus in the same moment when remote validation request is complete. What I think it happens then is callback function in executeAfterCurrentAjaxCall is executed immediately, and in that moment jquery validation response is not finished yet, so `$(caller).valid()` returns false. I still do not know how `alert("field is valid")` helps in that scenario, and that could be sign that I'm wrong and something else is happening. However, changing executeAfterCurrentAjaxCall so it looks like this seems to solve my problem:

```
function executeAfterCurrentAjax(callback) {
    if (ajaxCounter > 0) {
        setTimeout(function () { executeAfterCurrentAjax(callback); }, 100);
    }
    else {
        setTimeout(callback, 10);
    }
}
```

Comment: It is a workaround, not real solution, so I will leave question open for a few more days in case someone comes with a better answer.